# How can I use only one node server for Angular SSR in NX Angular

Tags: nomachine-nx, angular-devkit, angular-ssr, nx-angular

I have an NX Angular monorepo with almost 40 applications. I want to use Angular SSR for the apps, but based on the standard implementation, this means I would have to run and maintain 40 node servers on the server - one for each app.

Is it good practice to have such amount of servers running? Or just one server doing just SSR, and if so, how to implement this?

Theoretically, I can use routing and maintain just one `server.ts`, but the `nx build app:server` required for prod SSR uses the `@angular-devkit/build-angular:server` executor to output basically the server bundled with the angular app - `main.js`